# setup:upgrade error when updating magento 2.2.7 to magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, php-7

I hope somebody has een idea to solve this, I tried removing all my cache, generated folder, composer install, compile etc but no luck

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql::getSchemaListener() in /data/web/current/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php:933
Stack trace:
#0 /data/web/current/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(831): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), 'schema', Array)
#1 /data/web/current/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/UpgradeCommand.php(122): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema(Array)
#2 /data/web/current/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UpgradeCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /data/web/current/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(893): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /data/web/current/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(262): Symfony\Comp in /data/web/current/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php on line 933
```

Composer file

```
{
    "name": "magento2",
    "description": "Magento2 platform",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.0",
        "mageplaza/module-core": "^1.3",
        "mirasvit/module-helpdesk": "^1.1",
        "dealer4dealer/xcore-magento2": "^2.1",
        "mirasvit/module-rma": "^2.0",
        "mageplaza/magento-2-german-language-pack": "dev-master",
        "plumrocket/module-autoinvoiceshipment": "^2.1",
        "mageplaza/module-smtp": "^1.2",
        "honl/magento2-nl-nl": "^1.1",
        "mirasvit/module-cache-warmer": "^1.2",
        "mageplaza/magento-2-dutch-language-pack": "dev-master",
        "geissweb/module-euvat": "^1.3",
        "mollie/magento2": "^1.4",
        "magmodules/magento2-channable": "^1.4",
        "myparcelnl/magento": "^2.4",
        "myparcelnl/sdk": "^v1.5",
        "mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate": "^2.21",
        "yotpo/module-review": "^2.4",
        "pelago/emogrifier": "2.0.0",
        "ethanyehuda/magento2-cronjobmanager": "^1.6",
        "msp/recaptcha": "^2.0",
        "xtento/advancedorderstatus": "^2.1",
        "mageworx/module-ordereditor": "^3.4"
     },
    "require-dev": {
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.13.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "2.3.9",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.3.1"
    },
    "replace": {
    "vertex/module-tax": "*"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "version": "2.3.0",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
"repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override",
        "patches": {
           "magento/module-quote": {
                "Fix issue getting rates while placing order from Admin panel": {
                    "source": "https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/9c066ca1cc2f2db9e66575da25992ca9bb74f65a.patch",
                    "level": 5
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was occurring as we have overridden the `Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql` class through a custom module. The new version of the core file in Magento has some changes to it, this error was because of those changes.

For fixing the same I reverted the override and made sure the file being called has the changes added by the new version of Magento.